# Passing objects between objects in Obj C

Tags: objective-c

I am passing several objects between two classes, say a string from A to B, by assigning the string to a string property in class B, which is of type retain. Will I have to release this string property in class B in its dealloc method?

Comment: Yes you have to in non-ARC. You should consider using copy instead of retain for strings, still you have to release it in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If the property type is retain, than it will increase retain count by 1, and to release an object you need to reduce its retain count to 0. 
So if you won't release it will cause memory leak. 
Infect that is the purpose of retain property, it gives ownership to the instance of that class implementing property.

Comment: We use retain property when we are not sure that source going to retain the object or not.

Answer (score 1):

As you are talking about `dealloc`, I am taking your issue as non-ARC.

> assigning the string to a string property in class B, which is of
>   type retain. Will I have to release this string property in class B

NO.

You need to release only when you do retain, copy, alloc.

Also, NSString should be assign not retain.

Comment: retain or assign attributes depends on his task.

Comment: what if I do not use that property at all in the later code, depending on runtime conditions, so that property will be nil till the end...should i check whether a property is nil before releasing something in dealloc?

Comment: as you are assigning, so need to fear for leak.

Comment: what if i have strong properties in a class with ARC enabled, which are set with values from a non-ARC class? can they cause a memory leak, since I cannot release them in dealloc as the code is ARC?

Comment: No need to dealloc. As Arc will put [... release] if required at compile time. And if you are not CARing (copy alloc retain) no need to release.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to release retained object. In dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if (_yourString)
    {
        [_yourString release];
    }

    ...

    [super dealloc];
}
```